# windows service acting as a web service

Tags: web-services, windows-services

I read that there are two kinds of services :

- web services : use on the server and offer to the client to use some of its methods.
- windows services : used to run some background task.

Is it possible to combine both? like for example write a windows service with a file watcher and add a web method to that service which can be called from a distant computer to launch some specific task? Or at the opposite is it possible to use a web service as a windows service ?

Comment: Simply have the windows service host a WCF service.